# index not appearing after using the right commands

Tags: indexing, debugging, makeindex

So I am currently writing my thesis.

I used the following snippet

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

Blah

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{theindex}
\index{Blah}

\end{theindex}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The document gets created and a new page is devoted to titled Index, but the index numbering is not appearing. Is there any reason?

Comment: Welcome, your cllaiming to use the right commands. But are you using the right tools? A program that creates your index would also include the call for `\begin{theindex}`, as well as the index. So i am a bit confused. Please post a minimal working example.

Comment: the document you show looks wrong not right, the `\index` command is supposed to go in your main text, not inside a `theindex` environment. The `theindex` environment is then generated by the `makeindex` program by sorting the output from `\index` so it should not appear in the document.

Answer (score 2):

Your document should look like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}


Blah\index{Blah}



\printindex
\end{document}
```

Then run `pdflatex` once (it will warn of no `.ind` file) then run `makeindex` which will generate the index, then run `pdflatex` again so the index file is included.

I deleted the `theindex` environmemt (as this is generated by `makeindex` and I  deleted `\thispagestyle{empty}` as you need page numbers to make sense of the index.

producing a two page doc as below:

[image]